# What's our position on questions of the form "Are there any plans for a new series of X?"?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, questions

Today I came across two old questions (both by the same user and posted on the same day, oddly enough) which are very similar in form but have been treated very differently:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-there-any-plans-for-a-new-star-trek-tv-series (**closed, 3 pending votes to delete**)
- [Are there any plans for a new Babylon 5 series or movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48/are-there-any-plans-for-a-new-babylon-5-series-or-movies?rq=1) (**open, has never been closed**)

This seems rather silly. Whatever our position is on such questions, it should at least be *consistent*. Unless there's some difference I'm missing between these two questions, they should either *both* be closed or *both* be open. The purpose of this meta post is to find out which.

### What is the community's position on such questions?

<sub>If anyone finds more examples like these two questions (whether open or closed), give me a link and I'll edit them in.</sub>

**Update**: the second of the above questions has now also been closed, and the first has been deleted. Seems fairly conclusive.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30850/were-there-any-plans-for-dollhouse-season-3

Comment: --^ open still.

Comment: @Mithrandir that's different; that's not asking "will there be?" but "_were_ there plans for?"

Comment: @Mithrandir yeah, what SQB said. Which makes a big difference, because the answers to that question aren't going to go out of date.

Comment: Except the answer on Star Trek, right now, is ***YES*** -- so what's the position on that?

Comment: @ThePopMachine And in the future, when the next Star Trek series has been and gone and there are no plans for a new one? And then there *are* plans for a new one again - and then that one comes and goes too? As I was once told in my early days on SE, **"questions shouldn't be moving targets"**.

Comment: @randal'thor, yes,  I agree,  and voted to delete.  Just pointing out the existing answers were factually incorrect too.

Comment: @randal'thor:   I agree with the spirit.   But any question that relates to a changing canon is a moving target.   Any answer to pretty much anything you can ask about Star Trek or Star Wars may need a modification in the future unless it's about a specific past event/episode.

Comment: @ThePopMachine True, but there's a difference between a question that *may* need modification (e.g. from "we don't know" to "this is the answer") when new canon appears and a question which *by its very nature* is liable to have answers that go out of date.

Comment: @randal'thor:  yep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe these questions **should be closed** because they usually can't be answered and tend to **encourage speculative answers**. Arguably they're a special case of our existing "future works" policy. Both of the examples linked by the OP contain what I would consider speculative answers.

The exception would be questions that explicitly exclude the future in some way, e.g. "Were there plans to make another X before Y happened?", since the answer to that won't change even if a new X does get made someday.

Answer (score 2):

I see these questions as completely objective. **Are there any plans<sup>1</sup>?** - you can answer this with Yes or No; and then back up with the appropriate evidence.

Speculative answers indicate a problem *with those answers*, not with the question.

<sub>1 Of course, you really need to ask if there are any *plans that have been made public* but the gist of the question is clear to me.</sub>

Comment: Down voting because I disagree with `Speculative answers indicate a problem with those answers, not with the question.` see Ixrec's answer.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: thank you for the downvote explanation. Ixrec's answer inspired that sentence.